# Adding the required attribute to conditional fields

Tags: javascript, forms, conditional-statements, required

I'm using this script:

```
 $.fn.conditionize = function(options){ 

         var settings = $.extend({
            hideJS: true
        }, options );

        $.fn.showOrHide = function(listenTo, listenFor, $section) {
          if ($(listenTo).is('select, input[type=text]') && $(listenTo).val() == listenFor ) {
            $section.slideDown();
          }
          else if ($(listenTo + ":checked").val() == listenFor) {
            $section.slideDown();
          }
          else {
            $section.slideUp();
          }
        } 

        return this.each( function() {
          var listenTo = "[name=" + $(this).data('cond-option') + "]";
          var listenFor = $(this).data('cond-value');
          var $section = $(this);

          //Set up event listener
          $(listenTo).on('change', function() {
            $.fn.showOrHide(listenTo, listenFor, $section);
          });
          //If setting was chosen, hide everything first...
          if (settings.hideJS) {
            $(this).hide();
          }
          //Show based on current value on page load
          $.fn.showOrHide(listenTo, listenFor, $section);
        });
      }


     $('.conditional').conditionize();


   $('.showhide').click(function() {
       $('#target').toggle('slow');
   });
```

To show/hide form fields. How do I add the required attribute to this initially hidden set of fields, after they are revealed? IOW, these fields only display if the answer to a previous question is "yes", but I don't want these fields to be required if they answer "no."

Comment: so toggle the attribute when you toggle the visibility?

Comment: yes, so maybe I need to add a setAttribute line?

Comment: well not sure why you would use setAttribute when you are suing jQuery https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45961503/how-to-add-and-remove-a-required-attribute-with-a-toggle