# Input fields required if certain select option is selected in a HTML form

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make the textbox required when select option is selected and submit.

When I select Education then input for Education is required
When I select Business then input for Business is required 
When I select Business & Education then both inputs are required.  is required

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```js
function changePurpose(){
    if(document.getElementById('TravelPurpose').value == "Education")
        {
            document.getElementById('PoT_Ebudget').setAttribute("required","");
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById('PoT_Ebudget').setAttribute("required","");
        }
    if(document.getElementById('TravelPurpose').value == "Business")
        {
            document.getElementById('PoT_Bbudget').setAttribute("required","");
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById('PoT_Bbudget').setAttribute("required","");
        }
    if(document.getElementById('TravelPurpose').value == "Education & Business")
        {
            document.getElementById('PoT_Bbudget').setAttribute("required","");
            document.getElementById('PoT_Ebudget').setAttribute("required","");
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById('PoT_Bbudget').setAttribute("required","");
            document.getElementById('PoT_Bbudget').setAttribute("required","");
        }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<form id="myform">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group options">
                <label class="form-label" for="purpose"> Purpose of Travel</label>
                <div class="controls" onchange="purpose(this)">
                    <select class="form-control" id="TravelPurpose" name="PoT_TravelPurpose" onchange="changePurpose()" required>
                        <option selected value="">Select Travel Purpose</option>
                        <option value="Business">Business</option>
                        <option value="Education">Education</option>
                        <option value="Education & Business">Education and Business</option>
                    </select>
                </div>                   
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="form-label" for="Budget"> Education</label>
                <div class="controls input-group primary">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                    <input type="number" style="text-align: right;" id="PoT_Ebudget" name="PoT_Ebudget"  placeholder="00.00" min="0" max="10000"   oninput="this.value = Math.abs(this.value)">
                </div>
                <br />
                <label class="form-label" for="Budget"> Business</label>
                <div class="controls input-group primary">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                    <input type="number" style="text-align: right;" id="PoT_Bbudget"  name="PoT_Bbudget" placeholder="00.00" min="0" max="10000" oninput="this.value = Math.abs(this.value)">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" >

</form>
```

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45961503/how-to-add-and-remove-a-required-attribute-with-a-toggle

Comment: Thanks, but my logic is different form what you shared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a field to become required by setting its `required` property:

Example:

```js
document.getElementById('PoT_Ebudget').required = true;

//...or

document.getElementById('PoT_Ebudget').required = false;
```

Also, it's a good idea to cache your element references in variables, for both improved code readability and performance.

```js
const PoT_Ebudget = document.getElementById('PoT_Ebudget');
const PoT_Bbudget = document.getElementById('PoT_Bbudget');

function changePurpose(){
    const value = document.getElementById('TravelPurpose').value;
    PoT_Ebudget.required = (value == "Education" || value == "Education & Business");
    PoT_Bbudget.required = (value == "Business" || value == "Education & Business");
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<form id="myform">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group options">
                <label class="form-label" for="purpose"> Purpose of Travel</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <select class="form-control" id="TravelPurpose" name="PoT_TravelPurpose" onchange="changePurpose()" required>
                        <option selected value="">Select Travel Purpose</option>
                        <option value="Business">Business</option>
                        <option value="Education">Education</option>
                        <option value="Education & Business">Education and Business</option>
                    </select>
                </div>                   
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="form-label" for="Budget"> Education</label>
                <div class="controls input-group primary">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                    <input type="number" style="text-align: right;" id="PoT_Ebudget" name="PoT_Ebudget"  placeholder="00.00" min="0" max="10000"   oninput="this.value = Math.abs(this.value)">
                </div>
                <br />
                <label class="form-label" for="Budget"> Business</label>
                <div class="controls input-group primary">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                    <input type="number" style="text-align: right;" id="PoT_Bbudget"  name="PoT_Bbudget" placeholder="00.00" min="0" max="10000" oninput="this.value = Math.abs(this.value)">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" >

</form>
```

Comment: I have updated the answer to make the code even more simple, if you're interested in that.